# Mariadb JSON_EXTRACT with condition on Json object

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, mariadb-10.3

How do I extract only value based on "id" = "BAR"

```
+------------------------------+
| data                         | 
+------------------------------+
| {"id": "FOO", "code": "FOO"} | 
| {"id": "BAR", "code": "BAR"} |
+------------------------------+
```

desired output

```
+------------------------------+
| code                         | 
+------------------------------+  
| BAR                          |
+------------------------------+
```

I tried with this but it does not work.

```
 SELECT 
 JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$[*].code') as code
 FROM TABLETEST 
 where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$[*].id')) ='BAR'
```

Answer (score 0):

The more straight forward solution is to use:

`WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id"), 'BAR');`

Like:

```sql
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$[*].code') as code
FROM TABLETEST 
  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].id"), 'BAR');
```

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to get the data from the "code" column when the id = "BAR", the SQL you're looking for may simply be:

```
SELECT `code` FROM `data` WHERE id = "BAR"
```

Comment: It is a json object like [ {"id": "FOO", "code": "hello"} ,  {"id": "BAR", "code": "bye"} ]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this part: 
`where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$[*].id')) = 'BAR'` Generally when you use the WHERE keyword in SQL, it goes like this: `WHERE [column] = [value]` With that said, you may be able to achieve the desired result by doing this - `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$[*].code') as code FROM TABLETEST where id = 'BAR'`